# Injecting template HTML partials in Angular2

Tags: angular

After spending hours going down weird rabbit holes with ngTemplateOutlets, componentFactoryResolvers, and mussing around with ViewChild oddities... I'm thinking there has to be a better way.

I have a component whose html template is getting large. **Purely** for organizational purposes, I'd like to move some of the html into sub-templates (other files). I'd then like to just have one line in my master template to pull them in, but the scope and context for everything should remain the same.

I could get it to work by wrapping up everything in its own component but that seems like a waste, and I'd need to have @Output eventEmitters all over the place, also seeming like a waste.

The closest to "good" I've found is [innerHtml], but obviously this won't work since Angular2 doesn't process the html it throws in. I'm honestly surprised there isn't a straight forward way to do this... it doesn't need to do any thinking just a simple way to inject some inline text which gets processed as normal.

Optimal solution would look something like

```
<div>
    all my regular content
</div>

<template [ngExternalTemplate]="./app/home/templates/my-template.html"></template>
```

And all the html injected in that template would be accessible, and able to access, everything in scope and context that normal inline html would.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I hate watching the html get huge, but really it shouldn't be split up into multiple components since it's all managing the same view.

As a last resort I suppose I could a little replace action with gulp but that seems super hacky.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You should split your template into components instead of creating very large template. For you specific problem you'll need text preprocessor.

Comment: As mentioned in my question obviously I know I can split it up into multiple components, but do not feel that is appropriate for this case since it's all managing the same view and same dataset

Comment: yep so I ended up doing exactly that and splitting them all up into separate components... couldn't find a better answer

Comment: There is a nice simple explanation about how to preserve data-integrity and split main component (main form) into sub-components at the same time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42205058/862795