# Multiple child component inside form - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am working on big form, so i plan to truncate the form into multiple child components which helps for easy integration and maitainbility. Using form builder i am trying to implement this.

**mainform.html**

```
    <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formDetail);" [formGroup]="formDetail">
      <label>
        <span>Name</span>
          <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter emp name"
          formControlName="name">
      </label>
      <app-userinfo></app-userinfo> <!-- Child component 1 -->
      <app-useracc></app-useracc> <!-- Child component 2 -->
    </form>
```

**mainform.ts**

```
export class MainformComponent implements OnInit {
  formDetail: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.formDetail= this.formBuilder.group({
        name:'',
      userinfo: this.formBuilder.group({
        userid: '',
        userph: ''
      }),
      useracc: this.formBuilder.group({
        useracc: '',
        usertransfer: ''
      })
    });
  }
  onSubmit(value:User){
    debugger;
  }
}
```

**Console.log**

```
formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
```

Is it possible to nested form component as a seperate child ?

Comment: Looks like the fields in the child components can't access their parent `formGroup`. Have you used the `formGroup` directive inside your child components? Can you show the HTML for one of those?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use `Input()` and pass that sub-`FormGroup` to the child. I changed it a bit here and made the group named `useraccount` instead of `useracc` to separate the control from the group:

Your sub group for useraccount in your parent:

```
  ...
  useraccount: this.formBuilder.group({
    useracc: '',
  })
  ...
```

So, the related child component tag in the parent should look something like this:

```
<app-useracc [useraccount]="formDetail.controls.useraccount"></app-useracc>
```

And then add input in your child component:

```
@Input() useraccount: FormGroup;
```

and template could look like this:

```
<div [formGroup]="useraccount">
  <input formControlName="useracc">
</div>
```

Working [**sample**](http://plnkr.co/edit/cPmpJzRNJ24SDSDl7SRM?p=preview)

Comment: @RED.Skull how do we access this child value into my parent formgroup. Will any changes in the child control are accessible in parent form with `formDetail.value`?

Comment: @PraveenRawat Got notified when you commented on my answer, so I might as well answer you. As you can see in the Plunker I made, the values are accessible in parent. Objects are mutable in JS, so they are passed by reference, so your parent gets all changes made in child.

Comment: @AJT_82 can we also add dynamic controls to useraccount within child and access it in parent ?