# Combining Model-Driven Form Groups

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have an accordion component that I've created in Angular and in each drawer, there are some forms that a user will have to fill out. During this process, the user can either save their information to continue later, or, finish with everything and save it all.

The structure is similar to:

```
<accordion>
    <drawer1></drawer1>
    <drawer2></drawer2>
    <drawer3></drawer3>
    <drawer4></drawer4>
</accordion>
```

I'd like to use a Model-Driven form in order to accomplish my task and I'm in between two solutions:

- Build a FormGroup for each `drawer` component and merge them at the end or when and if the user decides to save for later
- Build a "master" form group at the `accordion` level and append to it as the user goes along.

I'd like to try solution #2 because let's say that I build a FormGroup with every possible input that the user will go to, and when they save, I can just submit what is filled out. Is that even possible/recommended in Angular? Any ideas on how to continue?

Thank you

Comment: Try something like this for option 2, that I would also recommend :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/42205058/6294072