# How to get angular component associated to a <form>tag?

Tags: angular

In my angular10 app, I am working on an unsaved changes modal in pages with multiple nested forms that shows up when the user navigates away. Given a 'form' tag, is there a way to locate all the associated child-components? Here is a sample layout:

Parent component:

```
   <form>
       <input formControlName="name" placeholder="Enter a name"/>
       <textarea formControlName="description", placeholder="Enter description"></textarea>
       <child-component></child-component>
   </form>
```

Child component:

```
 <child-component>
   <form>
     <!--some more details collected here-->
   </form>
</child-component>
```

An approach that I've explored is - making the 'parent-component' and 'child-component' implement a certain interface having a getForm() method, assign a template variable to both components and have a @ViewChildren(templateVariable) in a base class they extend and iterate over the QueryList to get the form pristine status.

I don't think [ng.getComponent](https://angular.io/api/core/global/ngGetComponent) would work here either.

Any other design suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you dont need form tag for the child component form in parent component. can you give me the sample json format to send data to api

Comment: <parent component>
<child component 1></child component 1>
<child component 2></child component 2>
<child component 3></child component 3>
</parent component>

it shows all the form in one view of parent component

Comment: @Gem - Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately that isn't the problem I am seeking help for. This is the layout I need to work with. I've updated the HTML to offer more clarity. Hope it helps

Comment: I do have to agree with @Gem, according to the HTML specs, forms should nog be nested. If you want to use child components, try using Angular's ReactiveFormsModule. That allows you to make practically any form with nested components. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203135/multiple-child-component-inside-form-angular-2

this answer may help you